# mysql string comma separated like %which one caused result?%

Tags: php, sql, string

I have a very complex issue that Me and my coworker have been discussing for a long time today and we just can't seem to get to the answer, wondering if anyone here has a bright idea we have missed.

```
$tags=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["tags"]);
$tags="SELECT * FROM i WHERE tip LIKE '%".$tags;
$tags=str_replace(",","%' OR tip LIKE '%",$tags);
$tags=$tags."%'";
$qtags = mysql_query($tags) or die(mysql_error());
```

example: $tags='word,phrase,term,foo,bar,anything'

tags are pulled from a paragraph written by a user and then compared with paragraphs stored in 'i' (sql database).

the problem we are facing is how to identify what/which 'tag' (out of the tags string) caused the result.

example: the resulting paragraph was like the tag 'foo' from the string $tags which was 'word,phrase,term,foo,bar,anything' how can we identify foo as the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN tip LIKE '%foo%' then 'foo'
         WHEN tip LIKE '%bar%' then 'bar'
         WHEN tip LIKE '%anything%' then 'anything'
    END as MatchedTag,
    i.*
FROM i
WHERE tip LIKE '%foo%'
   OR tip LIKE '%bar%'
   OR tip LIKE '%anything%'
```

It would need to be generated from your `$tags` variable like your current query.

Comment: I've never seen this before -> i.*

Comment: That just means select all fields from table `i`.  It's identical to saying `select *` when you're selecting from only one table.  In this case it has no effect, just a habit of mine that slipped in.